# Objective-C semantic equivalent written in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I'm rewriting a standalone macOS application based on Quartz Composer's composition. I'm running Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

The problems is `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings()` exists only in Objective-C. What's Swift's equivalent?

Objective-C version:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    qcView = [[QCView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.window.contentView frame]];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:qcView];

    [qcView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(qcView);
    [self.window.contentView addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[qcView]|"
                                         options:0
                                         metrics:nil
                                         views:views]];

    [self.window.contentView addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[qcView]|"
                                         options:0
                                         metrics:nil
                                         views:views]];
    
    if(![qcView loadCompositionFromFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"qtz"]]) {
        NSLog(@"test.qtz failed to load");
        [NSApp terminate:nil];
    }

    NSLog(@"test.qtz has been loaded");

   [qcView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"patch.Count.value" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
   [qcView setEventForwardingMask:NSAnyEventMask];
   [qcView startRendering];
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
                                         ofObject:(id)object
                                         change:(NSDictionary*)change
                                         context:(void*)context {

    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"patch.Count.value"]) {
        int val = [[qcView valueForOutputKey:@"Count"] intValue];
        NSLog(@"%@ = %d", keyPath, val);
    }
}
@end
```

Swift version:

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var view: NSView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let qcView = QCView(frame: self.window!.contentView!.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(qcView)

        qcView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var views: [NSObject : AnyObject] = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(qcView)   
        self.window!.contentView!.addConstraints( NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[qcView]|", options:[], metrics: nil, views: views))        
        self.window!.contentView!.addConstraints( NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[qcView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))

        if !qcView.loadCompositionFromFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "qtz")!) {
            print("test.qtz failed to load")
            NSApp.terminate(nil)
        }

        print("test.qtz has been loaded")
        qcView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "patch.Count.value", 
                                    options: .new, 
                                    context: nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings()` isn’t just UIKit, FYI.